# ruby motion LoadError: cannot load such file -- cocoapods/sources_manager

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

Trying to install AFNetworking in this RubyMotion application. I've followed the steps [here](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/articles/cocoapods/) on the ruby motion website. Using ruby-2.1.0 , when I run rake install I get

the error

ruby motion LoadError: cannot load such file -- cocoapods/sources_manager. sudo motion update is on the latest version.

looking for tips..cheers!

Comment: upgrade to rails 2.1.2, reinstalled everything and it works now.

Comment: I know its nitpicking, but you mean ruby 2.1.2?